# Calling Spring Boot method from terminal

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, method-call, mainclass

I am researching how to call a method from the terminal.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationAdapter implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private IApplicationPort iApplicationPort;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        iApplicationPort.getAll();
        iApplicationPort.deleteStudentById((long) 1);
    }
}
```

This is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        new ApplicationAdapter();
    }
}
```

I wish to call the 2 methods: `getAll();` and `deleteStudentById((long) 1);` from the terminal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

First you don't need to instantiate the ApplicationAdapter. This will be done by Spring because of the @Component annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        // new ApplicationAdapter(); REMOVE
    }
}
```

Then you could use parameters that you pass when staring the application:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationAdapter implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private IApplicationPort iApplicationPort;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        if (args[0].equals("all")) {
            iApplicationPort.getAll();
        } else if (args[0].equals("delete"))
            iApplicationPort.deleteStudentById(Long.parseLong(args[1]));
        } 
    }
}
```

Then you can start your app like:

```
java -jar yourApp.jar all

java -jar yourApp.jar delete 1
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful please accept the answer and upvote. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure this is non the right direction, but I'm getting ```Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at org.package.ApplicationAdapter.run(ApplicationAdapter.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:781) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
 ... 10 common frames omitted```

Comment: How do you call the program?

Comment: It fails at the time when I'm trying to start the program in IntelliJ